# GWT + IntelliJ Idea 9

Tags: gwt, plugins, intellij-idea

I downloaded IntelliJ Idea 9.0 community version and now I want to create a GWT application in it, but I am not getting that GWT option while creating the project.

I also saw some video on google but still not get solutions.

Do we have to add a plugin for IntelliJ Idea for GWT as we are doing it for Eclipse or what is the proper way?

Please reply me as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I would bet that IntelliJ 9 can support GWT right out of the box (it should include the GWT plugin), but you'll have to turn it on.  I'm using IntelliJ 8 still, but you can probably go to the File menu --> Configure plugins, and then look for it under JavaEE/Web plugins.

Comment: IntelliJ 8 includes the GWT plugin, but I'm not sure if it's turned on or not by default.

Answer (score 1):

I have been building gwt apps with the 9.0 community edition using the following build a configuration too run dev mode:

```
main-class: com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode
vm-params: -Xmx256M
program-params: -war \path\to\my\war -startupUrl index.html com.my.module.EntryFile
```

where your module descriptor is com/my/module/EntryFile.gwt.xml

Also make sure that have your java client source on run configuration's classpath along with gwt-user.jar, gwt-servlet.jar and gwt-dev.jar. Your source path is needed so devMode will pick up changes to your java code when rendering your application. It takes a little more work to set up a gwt project with idea9CE, but the price is right. I started by using webappCreator utility to initialize a project and then built my idea module around that.

If you are looking for a turn key solution, I think you will have to get the enterprise version, or use eclipse.

Comment: You use an absolute path to the war - did you find a way to use a relative path, or an environment / IntelliJ variable?

Comment: I had to add `-Dgwt.home=/path/to/gwt` to my Run/Debug for Intellij to use my GWT library.

Answer (score 1):

In version 10, there's a **File** > **New Module...** wizard where:

1. You add a module to your project using **Create module from scratch**
2. Enter a name and select type **Java Module**
3. Create the source directory (./src)
4. Check **Google Web Toolkit** and browse to your SDK to load the GWT libraries and facets.

One good thing about the wizard is that **Create sample application** is unchecked by default.